# How can i convert an int to a hexadecimal number and print it as a 3 digit number in c?

Tags: c, hex, converters

I need to code an int to a hexadecimal number, I know that the int wont take more than 3 hexadecimal digits. And i need to add zeroes to number if needed. Such that 7A ill be printed as 07A.

So i need to write a function that can convert an int to hexadecimal and add zeroes if the number has less than 3 hexadecimal digits.

I tried to make it work but i only found functions that convert an int to a string that represents the converted hexadecimal number.

Thank you.

Comment: `printf` can do it for you for free. Check how `%x` specifier works along with the width modifier

Comment: `int num = 0x7A; printf("0x%03X\n", num);`

Comment: Don't tell us that you have tried but show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the concept of base-conversion only makes sense in the context of textual representations of a number, I'm assuming you mean "I want to represent an `int` as a 3-digit hex number, with leading zeroes if it's not at least 3 digits wrong".

This is simple:

```
int myValue = /*whatever*/;
char strNum[10];

snprintf(strNum, 10, "%.3X", myValue);
```

`strNum` will now contain a hex representation of `myValue`. If it's less than three digits long, it will be padded with zeroes till it has length 3.

Comment: What if i need to use fprintf to print that into a file? Can i still use snprintf or store the result of snprintf?

Comment: Just use `fprintf` directly in that case. I used `snprintf` to show you how to save the hex representation into a string variable

Comment: Just replace the snprintf in fprintf? because it doesnt work

Comment: @DvirPeretz *No*; replacing the function name is not enough. Look at the documentation for `fprintf` and see how to use that

Comment: Read the docs and tried u_int16_t x = num;
    fprintf(file,"%03X",x); and this works, thank you.